# Setting a cookie for a parent domain

Tags: php, cookies, dns, setcookie

I am building an application using PHP and I came with this problem. I have the main domain and a subdomain called API. The domain contains my index php file and the website itself. The subdomain "api" makes all the requests for my app. It's like a Model-View-Control framework. The problem is I am setting a new cookie inside the api domain and it is not available on the parent domain. I am using this:

```
setcookie('name','value', time() + 3600, '/');
```

How can i solve this? Also I have tried to set the "path" parameter to 'domain.com' but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at [the PHP docs](http://php.net/setcookie), the next parameter after `path` is `domain`. Set it to `.domain.com` (the first period is important!) and it'll be valid for all subdomains.